# Testrpc command with mnemonic and account with preloaded ETH value

Tags: testrpc

Im trying to startup my testrpc with the mnemonic "-m" flag while also preloading a specific account with custom ETH amount.

This is the command I tried, but no luck. It starts up and preloads the account fine, it just does not have the accounts from the mnemonic.

```
testrpc -m 'help maple me bake pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat' --account='0xxxxxxxxx00xxxxxxx000xxxx,100000000000000000000'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mnemonic is used for re-generating the same set random account addresses.

But since you are specifically entering a private key with your `--account` tag, then it is only creating that specific account/address.

These two tags (`-m` and `--account`) are conflicting.

If you want to generate several accounts with the same private keys and addresses, you can repeat the `--account=''` tag multiple times for as many accounts as you want.  In which case, then you wouldn't need the mnemonic `-m` part.